# Error: `expo-modules-core` project is not included by autolinking

Tags: java, android, react-native

Noob react-native coder here. I just tried to recently add stack navigation and now the whole project blew up.... I can't solve successfully build the project anymore. Seems like the main issue here is `Error:` expo-modules-core `project is not included by autolinking.` But I've attempted to install this manually using npm, no luck.

```
tonyma@tonys-mac-mini react-native-app % yarn android       
yarn run v1.22.15
$ react-native run-android
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1713 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 8 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...
⚠️ react-native-unimodules is deprecated in favor of expo
⚠️ Follow this guide to migrate: https://expo.fyi/expo-modules-migration


> Configure project :expo

> Configure project :react-native-firebase
react-native-firebase: using React Native prebuilt binary from /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 28.4.2
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 19.2.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 12.9.3 (12,9,3 - 12009003)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 30
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 30
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 28.4.2
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 12.9.3 (12,9,3 - 12009003)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 30
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 30
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 21
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/android

> Configure project :react-native-plaid-link-sdk
Warning: The 'kotlin-android-extensions' Gradle plugin is deprecated. Please use this migration guide (https://goo.gle/kotlin-android-extensions-deprecation) to start working with View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) and the 'kotlin-parcelize' plugin.

> Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin

> Task :expo:compileDebugKotlin FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.8/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
159 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 156 up-to-date
Error: `expo-modules-core` project is not included by autolinking.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (16, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (30, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (57, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (63, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 41): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Error: `expo-modules-core` project is not included by autolinking.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (11, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (12, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 18): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (18, 23): Unresolved reference: createApplicationLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 10): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ApplicationLifecycleDispatcher.kt: (19, 20): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (10, 21): Unresolved reference: adapters
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (11, 21): Unresolved reference: core
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ExpoModulesPackage.kt: (16, 31): Unresolved reference: ModuleRegistryAdapter
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (22, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactActivityLifecycleListeners
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (53, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (60, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (66, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 37): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactActivityDelegateWrapper.kt: (73, 47): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 14): Type mismatch: inferred type is Unit but Iterable<TypeVariable(R)> was expected
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (23, 19): Unresolved reference: createReactNativeHostHandlers
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (30, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (57, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (63, 14): Unresolved reference: it
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 31): Overload resolution ambiguity: 
public inline fun <T> Iterable<TypeVariable(T)>.forEach(action: (TypeVariable(T)) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
public inline fun <K, V> Map<out TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>.forEach(action: (Map.Entry<TypeVariable(K), TypeVariable(V)>) -> Unit): Unit defined in kotlin.collections
e: /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/expo/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/ReactNativeHostWrapper.kt: (85, 41): Cannot infer a type for this parameter. Please specify it explicitly.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':expo:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s

    at makeError (/Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/execa/index.js:174:9)
    at /Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/execa/index.js:278:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (/Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/tonyma/codingPlayground/DineNDash/frontend/react-native-app/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: Follow this guide to solve the issue https://expo.fyi/expo-modules-migration